# How do I disable an input with Umbrella JS?

Tags: jquery, umbrellajs

The [UmbrellaJS docs for attr](https://umbrellajs.com/documentation#attr) mention that (similar to jQuery) one should know the difference between `attr` and `prop`. I've found some discussion on [using prop or attr for disabled in jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/project/tribune/issues/2033817#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20and%20change%20DOM,first%20message%20has%20been%20sent.) but all I know is Umbrella doesn't have `prop` and changing `disabled` doesn't seem to work in Umbrella:

`u('#my-input').attr('disabled', true);`

`u('#my-input').attr('disabled', false);`

(tagging jQuery because it's related and someone who knows jQuery well may be able answer this using their intuition)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot remove an attribute of an item.

If you wish to disable all elements you can do this

```
u('.permissionItem').each( function(e){e.disabled = false;});
```

Or if it is just one item, you can do

```
u('.permissionItem').first().disabled = false;
```

.first() and the foreach loop both give the node, instead of the umbrella element.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and even after doing what @Haroldo Gondim suggested, I could not remove the disabled attribute.  This is how I solved it...

```
u('#my-input').nodes[0].disabled = true;
u('#my-input').nodes[0].disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add it as a plugin if you are going to be doing this often:

```
u.prototype.prop = function(name, value) {
  // This will handle those elements that can accept a pair with these footprints:
  // .prop('a'), .prop('a', 'b'), .prop({ a: 'b' })
  return this.pairs(name, value, function (node, name) {
    return node[name];
  }, function (node, name, value) {
    node[name] = value;
  });
}
```

Then it should behave similarly to jQuery:

```
u('#my-input').prop('disabled', true);
u('#my-input').prop('disabled', false);
```